Why does Rust not reorder fields in an enum for memory layout?
I know that fields in Rust structs are automatically reordered to save memory (unless e.g. #[repr(C)] is specified).
I was under the assumption that the same is true for enums.
Today I was creating a simple helper type (the semantics of the example don't matter, this is about memory layout):
pub enum LazyRwLockGuardVersionA<'a, T> {
    Unlocked(&'a RwLock<T>),
    Read {
        lock: &'a RwLock<T>, // still neccessary for promoting to write lock
        guard: RwLockReadGuard<'a, T>,
    },
    Write(RwLockWriteGuard<'a, T>),
}

While a raw Read/Write Guard uses 16 bytes, this type uses 32.
In order to get the compiler to use the niche optimization I tried this version:
pub enum LazyRwLockWriteGuard<'a, T> {
    Unlocked(&'a RwLock<T>),
    Write(RwLockWriteGuard<'a, T>),
}

pub enum LazyRwLockGuardVersionB<'a, T> {
    Read {
        guard: RwLockReadGuard<'a, T>,
        lock: &'a RwLock<T>,
    },    
    NonRead(LazyRwLockWriteGuard<'a, T>),
}

This successfully brings down the memory usage to 24 bytes.

However, I noticed something weird:
When reversing the order of fields in the Read variant:
pub enum LazyRwLockGuardVersionC<'a, T> {
    Read {
        lock: &'a RwLock<T>, // order of fields reversed
        guard: RwLockReadGuard<'a, T>,
    },
    NonRead(LazyRwLockWriteGuard<'a, T>),
}

This type suddenly uses 32 bytes again.
My Rust Version is 1.77, here is a godbolt repro: https://godbolt.org/z/svE5v6Tr8


Are enum fields not allowed to be reordered by the spec, or is the compiler just 'lazy' here?
Is there a rough intuition for the algorithm that the compiler currently uses
for layouting enums, so I can understand this result, and prevent accidental pessimizations of my code in the future?


Niche optimization uses heuristics, and they are tweaked all the time. I don't think there is a specification somehow, other than the compiler's source.

I understand that. I'm not asking for a detailed explanation / specification.
I was just hoping for a rough understanding of why this could be happening.
Maybe the compiler lays out the enum's sub-structs first individually and does not revisit that decision later? Or is there something else going on?

Questions over (current) compiler implementation details are probably best directed at the IRLO forum or on Rust's Zulip chat.  That's not to say you won't necessarily get an answer here.

Or else perhaps file this as a bug on the GitHub issue tracker?  It seems reasonable to me that the Rust enum repr should be better at optimising layout here.


Are enum fields not allowed to be reordered by the spec, or is the compiler just 'lazy' here?

The default/Rust type layout is completely unspecified beyond soundness guarantees.  The compiler is otherwise free to do whatever it wants, and indeed this does change between compiler versions.

Is there a rough intuition for the algorithm that the compiler currently uses for layouting enums, so I can understand this result, and prevent accidental pessimizations of my code in the future?

If you want to have a guarantee of the layout, you must select a different representation.
